# PHP: if more than ..px resize to

Tags: php, resize, resize-image

I want to do so if the image are over the dimensions 604x453, then resize it to 604x453.

Ive made it this far:

```
    $org_name = stripslashes($_FILES[$upload_name]['name']);
    $file_size = $_FILES[$upload_name]['size'];
    $file_temp = $_FILES[$upload_name]['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES[$upload_name]["type"];
    $file_err  = $_FILES[$upload_name]['error'];
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $imageSizeInfo;
    $move_me = "images/users/status/".$org_name;
if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $move_me)) {
    echo "{";
    echo        "msg: '".$org_name."'";
    echo "}";
}
if($width > 604 && $height > 453) {
$jpeg_quality = 90;
$src = "images/users/status/".$org_name;
$ext= pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$targ_h = 453;
$targ_w = 604;
$path_thumbs = "images/users/status/";
$thumb_path = $path_thumbs . '/' . $newfilename;

if($ext == "jpg" OR $ext == "jpeg" OR $ext == "JPG"){
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}elseif($ext == "png" OR $ext == "PNG"){
    $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}elseif($ext == "gif" OR $ext == "GIF"){ 
    $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
}
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagejpeg($dst_r,$thumb_path,$jpeg_quality);

unlink($move_me);
}
```

So first it uploads the file with the original dimensions and everything, and then after it checks for dimensions and then resizes it, and unlinks(remove) the original one..

Now I dont know what, but somehow at the resize procedure it goes wrong and i only get a black square in the dimensions 604x453 as output..

What did i miss, how can i solve this?

Comment: You should consider doing a lot more input filtering then merely some "stripslashes"  on the filename.

Comment: @Berkes, thank for the comment, what more should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between your `ImageCreateTrueColor` and `imagejpeg` lines, you need something like this:

```
imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targ_w, $targ_h, $width, $height);
```

See the PHP manual for [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).

Your old code was essentially creating a blank canvas of the correct size, then creating your "black square" from it.

You should also use [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to determine what type of image has been uploaded, instead of using the file extension.

> Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX
>   constants indicating the type of the
>   image.

The reason for this is that it is perfectly plausible that an image is uploaded which is called `file.jpg`, but it is actually a `.png` file - `getimagesize()` examines the bytes inside the image to determine what format it is.

Comment: what if i check by exif_imagetype ?

Comment: @Karem: I've never used `exif_imagetype` personally, but from the manual, it looks good to use: "reads the first bytes of an image and checks its signature". Edit: "The return value is the same value that getimagesize() returns in index 2 but exif_imagetype() is much faster". You are probably already calling `getimagesize` somewhere though (where does `$imageSizeInfo` come from?), so you should probably stick with that.