# PHP: dimension of a rescaled image

Tags: php

This is a followup question to [PHP: if more than ..px resize to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639961/php-if-more-than-px-resize-to)

As you can see it resizes if:

```
if($width > 604 && $height > 453) {
```

This works fine is both the width and height are large.

However, if $width is over 604, and $height is under 453 (e.g. 604x300)m then this will skip the resize procedure. The opposite is the same(width is under, height is over). Also, if the dimensions on a picture is 500x900, and it gets resized, it gets really ugly resized. any great fix?

Any good suggestion on how I should handle this please?

edit:

```
$rel_difference = array('width'=>0, 'height'=>0);

if($width > 604 || $height > 453) {
    if($width > 604) $rel_difference['width'] = ($width-604)/604;
    if($height > 453) $rel_difference['height'] = ($height-453)/453;

asort($rel_difference);

$newwidth = $width/(1+end($rel_difference));
$newheight = $height/(1+end($rel_difference)); 
$newwidth = round($newwidth);
$newheight = round($newheight);
$jpeg_quality = 90;
$src = "images/users/status/".$org_name;
$path_thumbs = "images/users/status/"; 
$thumb_path = $path_thumbs . '/' . $newfilename;

switch(exif_imagetype($move_me)) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    break;
    default:
            echo "{";
            echo        "error: 'Not a image!'";
            echo "}";
        exit(0);
    break;
}
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $newwidth, $newheight );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth , $newheight, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($dst_r,$thumb_path,$jpeg_quality);

unlink($move_me);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do somthing like:

```
$width = 1000;
$height = 900;

$rel_difference = array('width'=>0, 'height'=>0);
if($width > 604 || $height > 453) {
    if($width > 604) $rel_difference['width'] = ($width-604)/604;
    if($height > 453) $rel_difference['height'] = ($height-453)/453;
}

asort($rel_difference);

print_r($rel_difference);
```

Which would output something like:

```
Array ( width] => 0.65562913907285 [height] => 0.98675496688742 )
```

Now you know the largest difference to max.

Which will be:

```
end($rel_difference);
```

So you can scale using this value proportional.

EDIT

removed unnecessary array_reverse

EDIT2

```
// now lets calculate the new dimensions based on our previous code
// I divide the dimensions with the largest difference + 1 to get to the new dimensions

$newwidth = $width/(1+end($rel_difference)); // 503.33333333333
$newheight = $height/(1+end($rel_difference)); // 453
```

The image is now proportionally scaled.

Don't know whether you can use that much decimals places if not use some rounding.

Comment: @PeeHaa thank you for your answer. What does this exactly do? I dont understand why you divide and so. Maybe you misunderstood the question, or maybe you could explain alittle further thank you!

Comment: @PeeHaa is this for scaling them by factor? How can i use these values? hope you can help me out, all new to scaling im always used to resizing to constant

Comment: You want to get the relative distance to max. Thats why I divide the numbers. You need this to figure out the largest distance to max and to scale to other dimension.

Comment: The height is the largest relative to max (it is 0.98675496688742 times max). So you want to scale both the width and the height down using this number. I'll update my answer. 1 sec plz

Comment: @Karem Check out my updated answer. If you have any more questions or if anything is still not clear just let me know.

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes im giving it a try now, how can i round up the number?

Comment: Several options: round() http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php to round to numbers of decimal places. floor() to round to bottom ceil() to round to ceiling

Comment: @PeeHaa ok just tested, wow it scales amazingly good, and doesnt disturb the picture at all. I will update my question in a minute, could you just tell me if everything looks ok (even though it works fine, just wants it confirmed please) thank you

Comment: Sure. No problem will check it out. Don't forget to mark as answer if it works for other user to see. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of you're logic in the statement, both must be true to execute the code.
You'll need an OR (||) in there not AND (&&).

```
if( $X > 500 || $Y > 300 ) {
    resize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($width > 604 && $height > 453) {
```

is TRUE only if both conditions are TRUE this means otherwise it is FALSE. If I get your question correctly then, if width = 605 and height = 300 then it is FALSE and nothing in the if block will be executed. (PS. 604 is not over 604)

Comment: Yes I know this, but then if a image is 605 and height 300 then the height will get expanded to 453, and i do not want this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a maximum height **or** width, you need to use `||` instead of `&&` in your conditional.

If you want to have images resize nicely, you'll need to scale them down by some factor instead of just resizing them using a constant. Not every image is the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

use [Image Processing (ImageMagick)](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

its very easy here are some [examples](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php)